# as3 Hex Value to Timestamp Conversion from Hex to MS-DOS: 32 bit Hex Value decimal

Tags: actionscript-3, datetime, hex, dos

i am trying to understand how to convert/decode a Hex Value in the MS-DOS: 32 bit format into human readable Date & Time. i have found a way to do this with Unix Hex timestamp/epoch to a normal date but does not work the same with my Hex Values which are in the MS-DOS: 32 bit format. anyone have any ideas?

```
var hex = "38BFFD44";
var decimal = parseInt (hex, 16);
var date = new Date(decimal*1000);
trace(date);
```

which should output:

```
Tue Jul 29 23:57:48 GMT+0000 2014
```

but instead outputs the date :

```
Fri Mar 3 17:58:28 GMT+0000 2000
```

i have tried adding compensation to the offset of the seconds to the date but this does not work it ends up out putting incorrect times and increasing the days. i am sure its something to do with the decimal conversion?:

```
date.seconds += 1402677061;
```

i have been reading more about the conversion from MS:DOS 32 bit and found this paragraph inside **"EnCase Computer Forensics -- The Official EnCE: EnCase Certified Examiner" -**

*"to properly combine and calculate this value, you must enter the hex values into a scientific calculator in the following order: 00 12 00 03. this converts the stored values to little endian. the resulting decimal value for this starting cluster world be 1,179,651."*

so i made a script to replicate this, but still does not seem to work..

```
function toDec(n:*, endianness: * = null): String {

    var bigEndian: Boolean;
    if (endianness == null) {
        endianness = Endian.BIG_ENDIAN;
    }
    if (endianness is Boolean) {
        bigEndian = Boolean(endianness);
    } else {
        bigEndian = endianness == Endian.BIG_ENDIAN;
    }

    var string: String = n.toUpperCase();

    if (!bigEndian) {
        var i: int = 0;
        var reversed: Array = [];
        while (i < string.length) {
            var byte: String = string.charAt(i++) + string.charAt(i++);
            reversed.unshift(byte);
        }
        string = reversed.join("");
    }

    return string;
}

var hex = "38BFFD44";
var sdecimal = parseInt(toDec(hex,Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN), 16);
var sdate = new Date(sdecimal);    

var bdecimal = parseInt(toDec(hex,Endian.BIG_ENDIAN), 16);
var bdate = new Date(bdecimal);

trace("small_endian.decimal = "+sdecimal);
trace("big_endian.decimal   = "+bdecimal);
trace("small_endian.date    = "+sdate);
trace("big_endian.date      = "+bdate);
```

Output:

```
small_endian.decimal = 1157480248
big_endian.decimal   = 952106308
small_endian.date    = Wed Jan 14 09:31:20 GMT+0000 1970
big_endian.date      = Mon Jan 12 00:28:26 GMT+0000 1970
```

Comment: Converting `38BFFD44` to decimal (just using the Programmer view on a regular Windows calculator) gives you 952,106,308 which if you pass it through an Epoch converter (such as http://www.epochconverter.com/) gives you `Fri, 03 Mar 2000 17:58:28 GMT`. Why are you expecting a different date?

Comment: [With MS-DOS, each portion of the time stamp (year, month etc.) is encoded within specific bits of the 32bit time stamp.](http://www.sandersonforensics.com/files/a%20brief%20history%20of%20time%20stamps.pdf)

Comment: thanks @JasonSturges i have this pdf doc but will read over again thanks for the heads up..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MS-DOS, each portion of the time stamp is encoded within specific bits of the 32-bit time stamp.

This is an [exFAT](http://ntfs.com/exfat-time-stamp.htm) timestamp:

```
╔═══════╦══════╦═════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════╗
║ Bits  ║ Size ║         Description         ║             Comments             ║
╠═══════╬══════╬═════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════╣
║ 0-4   ║    5 ║ Seconds (2-second interval) ║ 0..29 (29 represents 58 seconds) ║
║ 5-10  ║    6 ║ Minutes                     ║ 0..59                            ║
║ 11-15 ║    5 ║ Hour                        ║ 0..23                            ║
║ 16-20 ║    5 ║ Day                         ║ 1..31                            ║
║ 21-24 ║    4 ║ Month                       ║ 1..12                            ║
║ 25-31 ║    7 ║ Year (as offset from 1980)  ║ 0 represents 1980                ║
╚═══════╩══════╩═════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════╝
```

This is a structure of two WORDS (each WORD is a 16-bit unsigned integer) - FatDate and FatTime, as seen in [DosDateTimeToFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
BOOL WINAPI DosDateTimeToFileTime(
  _In_   WORD wFatDate,
  _In_   WORD wFatTime,
  _Out_  LPFILETIME lpFileTime
);
```

Parsing this hex value as a ActionScript [`date`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#Date()) as timestamp since epoch won't work.

In addition, there is an endianness issue.  This value must be little endian.

Converting your 0x38BFFD44 from big endian (952106308) to little endian (1157480248) produced your expected output.

In ActionScript, this should be:

```
var t:uint = 1157480248; // 0x38BFFD44 as little endian;

var date:Date = new Date(
    1980 + ((t & 0xfe000000) >> 25), // year
    ((t & 0x1e00000) >> 21) - 1,     // month
    ((t & 0x1f0000) >> 16),          // day
    ((t & 0xf800) >> 11),            // hour
    ((t & 0x7e0) >> 5),              // minute
    2 * (t & 0x1f)                   // second
    );
```

Outputs:

> Tue Jul 29 23:57:48 GMT-0500 2014

You will have to account for time zone offset for UTC.

References:

- [MSDN: How do I convert the timestamp to actual DateTime?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2007fc5a-4b6b-4a3d-8894-78f8e09826c1/how-do-i-convert-the-timestamp-to-actual-datetime)
- [MS-DOS date and time format](http://proger.i-forge.net/MS-DOS_date_and_time_format/OFz)

Comment: hi @JasonSturges thanks allot for this.. very helpful thanks! - will look into it in more depth unfortunately i am not 100% sure "exFAT timestamp" is the same as "MS:DOS 32 bit" i am 100%! sure that the Hex Value of: "38BFFD44" should result in the Timestamp of: "Tue Jul 29 23:57:48 GMT+0000 2014" i have checked this with RevEnge and Dcode applications and both are outputting the correct timestamps so if your code is off this can't be correct...sorry:( (the hex i have is meant to be outputted to LITTLE_ENDIAN).

Comment: thanks for those links i am just busy reading/testing that php code to see if i could translate it to actionscript if it outputs the correct timestamp.

Comment: i have also updated my question with some more code.

Comment: @whitedeath Converted to little endian, this function outputs your expected result; although, account for your time zone offset for UTC.

Comment: thanks this is great, with a combination of my code above to convert to LITTLE_ENDIAN this works! thanks again..